# The set of positive integers divisible by at least one element from a given set of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $(S_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint finite sets each containing 1 or more prime numbers. Define $C(S_i)$ to be the set of positive integers divisible by at least one element of $S_i$ for each $1\leq i \leq n$.

This set $C(S_i)$ is not simply the set of solutions to some system of congruence relations. However, membership of an integer $k$ in this set only depends on the residues of $k$ modulo the primes appearing in $(S_i)_{1 \leq i\leq n}$.

I am interested in: **How many elements of $C(S_i)$ are there in the first $N$ natural numbers?**

I am specifically interested in the case where $N$ is not a multiple of the period of $\mathbf{1}_{C(S_i)}(k)$ (the indicator function of the set $C(S_i)$).  In the case where $N$ is a multiple of the period (call this $P$), it is not hard to show that the number of elements less than $N$ is:

$$ P\prod_{1\leq i \leq n}\biggr(1-\prod_{z_1 \in S_i}(1-\frac{1}{z_1})\biggr)$$

I suspect but cannot prove that that the number of elements of $C(S_i)$ less than $N$ grows roughly linearly, but I am having a hard time finding hard upper/lower bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the number of elements of $C(S_i)$ in $[1, \ldots, x]$.
Since membership $k \in C(S_i)$ depends only on  $k \mod P$, if $m$ is the number of these in $[1,\ldots,P]$, we have $$f(nP+j) = f(j) + n f(P) \ \text{for}\ 0 \le j < P$$  So
yes, it is roughly linear, with bounds
$$  n f(P) \le f(nP+j) \le (n+1) f(P) $$
i.e.
$$ \lfloor x/P \rfloor f(P) \le f(x) \le \lceil x/P \rceil f(P) $$

Comment: This works, thank you